# Jquery select button by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand how to select by name with Jquery the button "g_list".

```
<div class="col-sm-4 sezione-na">
<div class="titolo-sezione-na">Title:</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12"><button name="g_list" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Generate list</button></div>
</div>
```

I wrote this Jquery code, but it doesn't work:

```
$("input[name='g_list']").click(function(){
alert( "ready!" );});
```

Comment: Maybe because you are selecting the `<input />` element while you are supposed to selecting the `<button>` element?

Comment: Because in all examples I whatched I found input selector. Sorry but I didn't found examples with jquery button selector.

Comment: @Fabio : `$("button[name='g_list']")`

Comment: Just change the `input` to `button` in your selector.

Answer (score 14):

In your code `input[name='g_list']` will be search input element with that name, instead you need to search for button so use `button[name='g_list']` for that.

```js
$("button[name='g_list']").click(function() {
  //--^------ change here
  alert("ready!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 sezione-na">
  <div class="titolo-sezione-na">Title:</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button name="g_list" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Generate list</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```